# Dynamic fetching of data file name and passion to sql in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

```
'fetching the file full name from from the range
Filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("FileEnv"). Value
'fetching the filename from the path fetched from above range
dataFile = FileNameFromPath(Filename)
'this function fetched the file name correctly as Product.csv
Sql = "select * from [dataFile]"
```

Now in the sql it's not fetching the data file as product.csv.It is takin dataFile only bcoznof which am getting an error of file not existing.

Help please?

Comment: What error do you have and where?

Comment: In the intermediate window, I see sql as select * from dataFile, whereas it should be select * from product.csv. the value of dataFile I.e product.csv should be in sql query.

Comment: good reference [Excel VBA Introduction Part 30 - ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) Querying a Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE9CIbetNnI&index=33&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  Please consider refactoring your question before refactoring your code.

Comment: Cn.open("provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLRDB.4.0;" & _ "Data Source = " & pathName &";" & _ "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;"""

Comment: @ThomasInzina it gives error as dataFile.text not found or doesn't exist.It is still taking dataFile as file name. It should take product.csv value that I have assigned to it  in my code description on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like:

`Sql = "select * from [dataFile]"`

Should be

`Sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & dataFile & "]"`

I merged you code with the example from [Much ADO About Text Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) to give you a better example.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim Filename As String, dataFile As String


    'Refernce: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

    On Error Resume Next
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("FileEnv").Value
    dataFile = FileNameFromPath(Filename)

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
              "Data Source=" & Filename & ";" & _
              "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & dataFile & "]", _
            conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    Do Until rs.EOF

    Loop

End Sub

Function FileNameFromPath(Filename As String) As String
    FileNameFromPath = Right(Filename, Len(Filename) - InStrRev(Filename, "\"))
End Function
```